# Иметь или представлять художественную ценность?

Tags: лексическая, лексическая-сочетаемость

Я никак не могу понять: произведение искусства имеет или представляет (собой) художественную ценность? Просветите?

Comment: Dear Noir.

Пожалуйста, не пользуйтесь выражениями, которые Вы никак не можете понять.

P.S.

1) Изделие i творца X имеет художественную ценность c в момент времени t, если в указанный момент времени лицо Y платит с долларов США владельцу Z указанного изделия.

2) В остальных случаях изделие i творца X представляет художественную ценность по мнению искусствоведа А либо по мнению искусствоведов B, C, D и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

ИМЕТЬ ХУДОЖЕСТВЕННУЮ ЦЕННОСТЬ – это обладать, располагать чем-либо.  В данном случае ценность как цена, которая, как известно, зависит от конъюнктуры: в какой-то момент предмет представляет художественную ценность, но ситуация может измениться.

ПРЕДСТАВЛЯТЬ ХУДОЖЕСТВЕННУЮ ЦЕННОСТЬ – это  быть, являться чем-либо. Если дословно, то  предмет рассматривается как представитель нашего понимания о  прекрасном.  Такая оценка более высокая и устойчивая во времени и зависит, скорее,  от художественного вкуса  человечества на данном этапе его развития.